Is it possible to check in one bag in advance and another on the morning of departure?
If you have an airport/airline that allows checking in bags the day before, and you've completed online check-in, is it possible to check in one bag in advance and another on the morning of departure?
I was going to ask a more specific question about doing this for an ANA domestic flight from Haneda, but as far as I can tell ANA baggage drop only opens at 6:25 AM the morning of your flight.

I have successfully checked in items of luggage in different interactions with agents at different stations. I don't think it mattered how much time passed between the interactions. But you'll probably have to ask the airline if they specifically allow it.

The airline I work for allows this, in fact, you can drop off one piece of luggage in the city terminal (a location inside the city where you can drop off your luggage the day before, and it will be transferred to the airport and get checked-in by the airline), and then check-in the rest of the luggage at the airport on the travel day.
If one airline does it, most likely many others do it as well.
